# in allocate_stack (stack=<synthetic pointer>, pdp=<synthetic pointer>

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am facing a segmentation fault while executing the following sample Program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<exception>
#include<stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class ThreadHandler
{
  public:
    int createThread(void (*function)(void*),void* input);
    void setThreadID(int);
    int getThreadID();
    void runThread();
    /* Constructor for ThreadHandler*/
    ThreadHandler();
    virtual ~ThreadHandler();
  protected:
  private:
    int mThreadID;
    pthread_t thread;
};

/* Function: ThreadHandler() */
ThreadHandler::ThreadHandler():mThreadID(0)
{
   cout<<"\n ThreadHandling - constructor"; 
}

/* Function: ~ThreadHandler() */
ThreadHandler::~ThreadHandler()
{
}

/*Function: setThreadID() - set mThreadID value after
  thread creation*/
void ThreadHandler::setThreadID(int thread_id)
{
  cout<<"\n setThreadID function Entry";
  mThreadID=thread_id;
  cout<<"\n Thread ID: "<<mThreadID;
  cout<<"\n setThreadID function Exit";
}

/*Function: getThreadID() - return a thread ID after
  thread creation*/
int ThreadHandler::getThreadID()
{
  return mThreadID;
}

/*Function: createThread() - Create Thread
  and Assign function dynamically */
int ThreadHandler::createThread(void (*callingFunction)(void*),void* input)
{
  cout<<"\n createThread Function Entry";
  int thread_id=pthread_create(&thread,(pthread_attr_t*)callingFunction,NULL,input);
  if(thread_id)
  {
     cout<<"\n Failed to create the thread and throw an exception";
     throw;
  }
  setThreadID(thread_id);
  cout<<"\n createThread Function Exit";
  return thread_id;
}

/* Function: runThread() -- Joinable thread for exection*/
void ThreadHandler::runThread()
{
  cout<<"\n Join the thread for runnable"<<endl;
  pthread_join(this->thread,NULL);
}

/*Function to execute by the thread*/
void ThreadFunction(void* input)
{
   cout<<"\n Thread Execution: "<<input;
}
/*Main part of the Class and Execution*/
int main()
{
   char* msgPtr="I am running";
   ThreadHandler *objThread = new ThreadHandler();
   if(objThread==NULL)
   {
      cout<<"\n Failed to create a ThreadHandler object";
      return -1;
   } 
   /*Create a function pointer to pass*/
   //void* (*FunctionPtr)(void*)=NULL;
   //FunctionPtr = &ThreadFunction;
   try
   {
      cout<<"\n -- start create a thread --";
      objThread->createThread(&ThreadFunction,reinterpret_cast<void*>(msgPtr));
   }
   catch(exception& e)
   {
      cout<<"\n Exception while creating the thread";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Error:
 ThreadHandling - constructor
 -- start create a thread --

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff76aab8c in allocate_stack (stack=, pdp=, attr=0x400ead )
    at allocatestack.c:415
415 allocatestack.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: You don't need to use `reinterpret_cast<void*>`. All pointers are implicitly convertible to `void*`. This is just a style thing though. Doesn't fix your segfault.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Looks like you are passing arguments to `pthread_create` in the wrong order.

From [man-pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

**Solution**

Change this:

```
pthread_create(&thread,(pthread_attr_t*)callingFunction,NULL,input);
```

to this:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, callingFunction, input);
```

**Suggestions**

I would suggest using [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) as it makes working with threads much easier, especially when coupled with [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: You need to remove the `(pthread_attr_t*)`. Should also use `0` or `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: @KurtStutsman Thanks. I was going to use `nullptr` from the beginning but wanted to remain consistent with OP's post. It looks like pre C++11 code in which case it wouldn't make much difference using 0 instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Even if it's pre C++11 I think it's good to teach people to use the proper coding style. `NULL` may not work depending on the how the compiler has implemented it. A lot of compilers have a `#define NULL ((void*)0)` and C++ will not auto-cast void pointers to any type like they do in C.

Comment: @KurtStutsman I absolutely agree. Thanks for your efforts. Feel free to edit next time :)

Comment: @Kurt The advantage of using `NULL` instead of `0` is that it provides useful additional semantic information and can easily be replaced for `nullptr` when you upgrade to C++11. The only advantage of `0` is that theoretically you could come across some stupid C++ library that defines NULL as you've said. I've never seen any that did though, but if that happened I'd do a global replace of NULL for 0 at that time and not before.

Comment: @All: Thanks for your inputs. Now its working fine. I have changed the NULL to 0.